# Riemann Integrability and Max-Min functions

Tags: continuity, riemann-integration

Suppose that $f$ is a bounded function on $[a, b]$ such that either $f^{+}=\operatorname{max}\{f, 0\}$ or
$f^{-}=\operatorname{max}\{-f, 0\}$ (but not necessarily both) is in $R[a, b]$. Does it necessarily follow that $f$ is also in $R[a, b]$?!

It seems that if both of these functions were in $R[a, b]$, then due to the famous formula $f = f^{+} - f^{-}$, once can easily derive the Riemann integrability of function $f$. However, in case if exactly one of them becomes Riemann integrable, is it necessarily true that $f$ will be integrable as well?! Is there any sufficient counterexample, since this seems to be wrong intuitively.

Comment: Isn't it $f = f^{+} - f^{-}$?

Comment: @fwd I guess the definition provided above seems to satisfy the division between difference and two

Comment: $$\max\{f, 0\} - \max\{-f, 0\} = \frac{f+|f|}{2} - \frac{-f + |f|}{2} = f$$

Comment: @fwd Yeah, it seems I made a mistake during the calculation, Thank you for specifying the relationship!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Define $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
-1  \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\\
0 \text{ if } x \not \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]
\end{cases}
$$

Then $f^{+} = 0$ and

$$
f^{-} = \begin{cases}
1  \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\\
0 \text{ if } x \not \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore, $f^{+} \in \mathcal{R}[0,1], f^{-} \not \in \mathcal{R}[0,1]$ and $f \not \in \mathcal{R}[0,1]$.

Comment: Is it necessary to prove that integral of zero equals zero as well?!

Comment: Well, if $f \equiv 0$ any partition $P$ you take will always give $U(P, f) = L(P, f) = 0$, so the integral exists.